# How to navigate between components in react-router-dom version 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I use `react@16.14.0` and `react-router-dom@4.3.1`. How do I navigate to another page with hook not `Link` and how to navigate back to page with hook. The `useHistory` and `useNavigate` hooks don't work because I am using `react-router-dom@4`.

I want to do `<Link to="/page"></Link>` with hook because I want pass data after navigate to other page.

I would like a solution for `useNavigate` in `react-router-dom@4`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is to pass some data when navigating you can do that with the `Link` component using the [`to`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v4.0.0/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md#to-object) prop object.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/page",
    state: {
      // data that you want to pass
    }
  }}
>
  Page
</Link>
```

Then access in the receiving component via the [route props](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v4.0.0/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#route-props).

```
<Route path="/page" component={Page}/>

const Page = ({ location }) => {
  const { state } = location;
  const {/* the properties that were passed */} = state || {};

  return (
    <h1>
      {/* the properties that were passed */}
    </h1>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

Using the `Link` component issues a ***declarative*** navigation action, e.g. it's rendered as part of the DOM and the user interacts with the UI. If you are instead looking to issue an ***imperative*** navigation action from a callback then you'll need to access the `history` object. `history` is also one of the route props.

```
<Route path="/" component={Home}/>

const Home = ({ history }) => {
  const navigateToPage = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/page",
      state: {
        // data that you want to pass
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    ...
    <button type="button" onClick={navigateToPage}>Page</button>
    ...
  );
}

export default Home;
```

The passed data is accessed the same way as above with the `Link`.

If a component isn't rendered via the `Route` component and passed route props then the component can be decorated with the [`withRouter`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v4.0.0/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) Higher Order Component available to it.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = ({ history }) => {
  const navigateToPage = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/page",
      state: {
        // data that you want to pass
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    ...
    <button type="button" onClick={navigateToPage}>Page</button>
    ...
  );
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Page = ({ location }) => {
  const { state } = location;
  const {/* the properties that were passed */} = state || {};

  return (
    <h1>
      {/* the properties that were passed */}
    </h1>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Page);
```

## Suggestion to upgrade to `react-router-dom@5`

`react-router-dom` v4 and v5 are generally considered to be the same *"version"*, most of the APIs remained the same and I believe it was only some internal implementations that necessitated a "major" release version bump. I'd suggest upgrading to `react-router-dom@5` which would allow you to use React hooks, e.g. [`useHistory`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) and [`useLocation`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation).

`npm run install --save react-router-dom@5`

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const navigateToPage = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/page",
      state: {
        // data that you want to pass
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    ...
    <button type="button" onClick={navigateToPage}>Page</button>
    ...
  );
}

export default Home;
```

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Page = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const {/* the properties that were passed */} = state || {};

  return (
    <h1>
      {/* the properties that were passed */}
    </h1>
  );
}

export default Page;
```